# Is there a way to get Apple's Swift language interacting with Java?

Tags: java, ios, api, swift

I've been given a Java API for my personal project. This means that all of the method calls and functions to utilize the API are in the Java programming language. However, I want to use Apple's new Swift language to create an iOS application that uses the API. So my question is as follows:

How can I get Apple's Swift language to interact with Java within XCode? In short, I want a button press in the Swift app to use the Java methods within the given API which will then create a file on a remote server and send it back to the device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any research into doing this yet? I'm pretty certain this isn't a thing that can be done. If there is actually a way, it'd blow my mind and I'd also like now

Comment: Not possible, you have to have the Java API somewhere other than the device. I second duffymo's answer to call it using webservices. Sounds like a good use of REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write web services in Java and let Swift UI invoke them via HTTP.  The separates the services from your UI and keeps that functionality available for others to use as well.

This means that the web services are deployed separately.  Your UI will send a request via HTTP and send it back to the device.  All the details about files or databases or how the data is derived are hidden from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, depending on circumstances, would be to use TCP/IP sockets. So you write a socket listener on your java server side, which would "wrap" the APIs, and you open and use the socket from your Swift App.

Or... you could use something like MQTT, a lightweight message-based protocol, with good iOS support.

There are many ways to do what you want. Perhaps you could supply some more detail about the actual topology involved.